# How do I do exponentiation in python?

Tags: python, math, operators

```
def cube(number):
  return number^3
print cube(2)
```

I would expect `cube(2) = 8`, but instead I'm getting `cube(2) = 1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: `**` is exponential, but doing multiplication when you know the exponent (i.e. `x*x` and `y*y*y` instead of `x**2` and `x**3`) is faster.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`^` is the [xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.

`**` is exponentiation.

`2**3 = 8`

Comment: There is also the builtin [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) and [math.pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow).

Comment: Can you explain how it works when there are fractions like `2 ** 4.5`?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Mind you, `math.pow` is basically 100% useless; `**` does the job without an import, and doesn't force conversion to `float`. And the built-in `pow` is the only one accepting three arguments to efficiently perform modular exponentiation. I can't think of a single time I've ever *wanted* to perform exponentiation that implicitly converted my integer inputs to floating point (the only time `math.pow` is even remotely useful, and `float(x) ** y` would achieve that anyway).

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the `math` library. For example:

```
import math
x = math.pow(2,3) # x = 2 to the power of 3
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to repeat it multiple times - you should consider using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def cube(number):
    # can be also called with a list
    return np.power(number, 3)

print(cube(2))
print(cube([2, 8]))
```

Comment: the essence of being **numpythonic**