# What does "e" in "1e-5" in Python language mean and what is the name of this notation?

Tags: python

I notice that there is such an expression "1e-5" in Python(probably in other languages also)

1. What is the name of this notation?
2. what does it denote in math?
3. What does 'e' mean? It's the first time I see a character helps to denote some value, are there other characters also help do so?
4. Why should use this way instead of some other python math operation like pow() etc.

Comment: Exponential notation: 1 * 10^-5... this has nothing to do with Python specifically, but math in general...

Comment: 1 × 10−5 is one of the values = "constant" (in c++ is a macro, in C# and Javascript is a const, in others...check) for a value  commonly called EPSILON.

In C++/python/c# and the languages which support IEEE standard for floating point arithmetic this is the value which separates any two floats/doubles values so adding or removing this value (as written in the question) generates the really next/previous value to the original value, so it acts as the delta which separates two floating point numbers.

x....epsilon....y

x+epsilon = y
y-epsilon = x

Answer (score 41):

It is [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). It means 1 × 10<sup>−5</sup>. In other words, 0.00001.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? because other sources say exponentiation should be done via `**`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python

Comment: `e` syntax is for floating-point number **literals**. The `**` operator is for performing a computation on two arbitrary **expressions**.

Comment: @information_interchange here is some documentation https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html

Comment: Official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals

Answer (score 16):

`10 ** -5`, i.e. 10 to the power of negative 5, 1 divided by 10 to the power of 5, or 0.00001.

Answer (score 4):

It means 10 to the power of -5 times 1