# Rewriting exponents for use in a loop

Tags: python

How can I rewrite this for use in a for loop?

```
# X to the Y
result = (X**Y)
print (result)
```

I know how to perform the for loop function but I can't remember how to write the  exponents.

Comment: `math.pow(x, y)`? Although what is wrong with `x**y`, that works in python as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with a for loop, even if it performs the wrong calculation.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. What do you mean "for use in a for loop"? What is the loop going to do?

Comment: Just a basic for loop this is not for any particular project i'm just trying to get back in the swing of python before i start my new job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are several ways of calculating an exponent in Python.

Some are covered in answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python).

```
# use X ** Y
print(X ** Y)

# use math.pow
print(math.pow(X,Y))

# use numpy
print(np.exp(X,Y))

# use a for loop
def pow(base, exponent): # integer exponent only
    ret = 1
    for _ in range(exponent):
        ret *= base
    return ret
print(pow(X,Y))
```