# What is the equation of this line in Python simple plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graphing

Please help me figure out what the equation for this line is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#start, stop, num (* is args [positional], ** is kwargs[keyword])
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

#this closes *args
plt.close('all')

#one figure and one subplot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_title("simple plot")
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.show()
```

The code runs, and sends back a graph, but I cannot figure out what the equation of the graph is.  Please help me, and if you can explain what the code did to graph that equation.  I am very new to python. :) thank you!

Comment: How is it not the sine of x squared from 0 to 2*pi?

Comment: `y = np.sin(x ** 2)`. It's in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do exponentiation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python)

Comment: Is someone just giving you code with no explanation for class?

Answer (score 0):

`x**2` means x to the power 2 in Python. In other programming language it is mostly noted as `x^2`. So your function is `y = sin(x*x)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  Very helpful! :)

Comment: In the x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400) line of the code, are those the parameters for the graph?

Comment: @Ava  `np.linspace` is a function that creates an array of 400 evenly spaced floats from 0 to 2 pi.

Comment: @Ava if the answer helped you would you be so kind to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the arrows on the left side?