# How to run calculations

Tags: python

I am new to programming and just started a course and stuck on a demo section where I have to take a math calculation and program it in Python. When I program it do you follow BEDMAS order of figuring out or is there a logical order. The syntax is correct but I keep being told it is not right

See the equation below to be programmed into python. What are the rules for telling Python to calculate something correctly where 5 is the exponent

Use Python to calculate `(((1+2)∗3)/4)5`

Comment: Hate to be this guy, but can you not google "Python exponentiation"?? See this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python/30149434

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiation in Python is done with the `**` operator.

For instance:

```
2**8
```

is `256`.

Comment: I know the operator but as my example above I keep receiving syntax errors. I can make it work up until I need to add in the operator and know matter what I try I keep getting syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

In Python to calculate exponent you use `**` operator.
Similar to multiplication but double asterisk.

```
(((1+2)∗3)/4)**5
```

This will give you 32.

That is because you are using values which are all integers, so 9 / 4 will be 2, not 2.25.

Python has [operator precedence](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity) that follows algebraic rules.