# How to raise to the power with a fraction in python

Tags: python

I'm looking to do the following in python:

```py
[0.12 x 1.616 x (100 x 0.019 x 40)^1/3] x 300 x 527.5
```

I can't work out how to raise to the power of a fraction. I want the output to be decimal.

```py
(100 x 0.019 x 40)^1/3
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do exponentiation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python)

Comment: exponentiation is "**"; you used bitwise XOR.
You also need to learn operator precedence: Exponentiation is always higher than division, so you have to put the division in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

To raise a number n to power p, you can use the [power operator `**`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

```py
n ** p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `math.pow` function:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(27, 1/3)
3.0
>>> help(math.pow)
Help on built-in function pow in module math:

pow(x, y, /)
    Return x**y (x to the power of y).
```

Or simply the `**` (exponent) operator:

```py
>>> 27 ** (1/3)
3.0
```

Also be careful of your order of operations:

```py
>>> 27 ** 1/3  # same as: (27 ** 1) / 3
9.0
>>> 27 ** (1/3)
3.0
```