# I was trying to solve a sum problem. when I run the script I think it's going forever, any tips?

Tags: python, sum

```
total = 0
k = 0

while total < 2000:
    k += 1
    total = 10*k^2-4*k+2+total

print("The number of terms is:", k)
print("The sum is: ", total)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do exponentiation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148740/how-do-i-do-exponentiation-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Add `print(total)` to your loop and the answer will become clear. Always check values if things aren't doing what you expect. It's easy to do and will often give you the answer immediately.

I suspect the core of your problem is that you expected `^` to be the exponentiation operator, while it's actually `**`.